# MongoDB how to run aggregate query on items with unique values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `metadata` collection with fields like:

```
{ _id: "...", value: "somevalue1", filename: "foo" },
{ _id: "...", value: "somevalue1", filename: "bar" },
{ _id: "...", value: "somevalue1", filename: "foo" },
{ _id: "...", value: "somevalue2", filename: "foo" },
```

I am currently getting a count grouped by filename, such as:

> foo: 3 bar: 1

But what I would really like, is make it count based on `value` too, whereas each value should be counted only once.

So results should be:

> foo: 2 bar: 1

My current code is as follows (there are some hacks in it to make it work with Meteor):

```
var sub = this;
    var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

    var pipeline = [
        { $group: {
            _id: {$ifNull: [ "$data.filename", "NULL" ]},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }}
    ];

    db.collection('metadata').aggregate(
        pipeline,

        Meteor.bindEnvironment(
            function(err, result) {
                _.each(result, function(e) {
                  sub.added('installSummary', Random.id(), {
                    filename: e._id,
                    total: e.count
                  });
                });
                sub.ready();
            },
            function(error) {
                Meteor._debug( "Error doing aggregation: " + error);
            }
        )
    );
```

Comment: Is there any particular reasons that you are using native mongo driver for aggregation instead of mongo aggregation support in Meteor like `meteorhacks:aggregate`?

Comment: no, except for I don't know how to use anything else, I hacked first solution together based on SO. I suck at this.

Comment: I think you have to group with $addToSet value field,$unwind,and group with $sum again.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake Did you check my answer? Does it not work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "two" [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stages. One to get the unique combined fields, and then you just get the unique "filename" values from each of those results. It's a "pipeline", so there is nothing wrong with doing that as each stage feeds input to the next:

```js
var pipeline = [
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "value": "$value", "filename": "$filename" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.filename",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
];
```

Which makes the results:

```js
{ "_id": "foo", "count": 2 }
{ "_id": "bar", "count": 1 }
```

Since the first `$group` reduced the "somevalue1" and "foo" combination to one unique entry.

Not sure why you have this prefixed with `data` since your sample does not reflect that structure, but if it is different then change that in the first pipeline stage.

Also there is no need for [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/), since `null` will be the default value anyway if the field does not exist.

Comment: Can you modified this like "foo: 2 bar: 1" ?

Comment: @AlokDeshwal The aggregation framework cannot dynamically create keys from data, and this is a good thing as things that are "data" should stay that way. Making data points the names of keys is not a good design pattern. If you really must then you can set up the transformation in the part where you process the resulting collection items to publish. Fairly trival pure object manipulation.

Comment: @ Blakes Seven what may be other ways to get the same out put for this problem

Comment: @AlokDeshwal Perhaps you should ask your own question since this is not your question. Then people can give answers specific to your case.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works very well. Now I'm wondering, if there is any way to modify the pipeline to produce both results, with total and unique counts of `value`. Cheers.